# Fedora set capture device to demorse

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, fedora

I'm using a program called [demorse](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/demorse/) (official page is down a the time of this writing).
On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS it works fine when I run it like this:

```
$ demorse -phw:0
```

That means: Use hw:0 as DSP device, and use the defaults including "capture device=line" (specified on documentation and displayed with `-h` option).

When I try to run the same command in Fedora 19 I get an error:

```
$ demorse -phw:0
demorse: setting dsp device to hw:0
demorse: Cannot find capture element Line
```

Then I tried (F19):

```
$ demorse -phw:0 -rhw:0
demorse: setting dsp device to hw:0
demorse: setting recording source to hw:0
demorse: Cannot find capture element hw:0
```

It doesn't work. However following an example from this [wiki](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=USB_mic_on_Linux#Recording_with_ALSA) I was able to make a recording using this command (F19):

```
$ arecord -f cd -D hw:0 -d 5 test.wav
```

**Is there a way to set the recording device as it is on Ubuntu (using "line")? 

Or is there another way to specify the recording device?**

Misc: 
1 (F19): I tried changing it to hw:0,0 | hw:0,1 | hw:1,0 ... but I get the same error message. 
2 (F19):

```
$ arecord --list-devices
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

3 (F19):

```
$ cat /proc/asound/pcm
00-00: ALC269VB Analog : ALC269VB Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
```

4 (F19): Changing `-p` value just gives an error message saying: `demorse: Cannot open audio device hw:0,1` (I tried several options too).